# Errors running flume agent with interceptor

Tags: java, hadoop, flume

I am trying to run custom flume agent from terminal using linux. I am working on cloudera VM. Command running flume looks like:

```
flume-ng agent --conf . -f spoolDirLocal2hdfs_memoryChannel.conflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n Agent5
```

Sources with interceptor looks like:

```
Agent5.sources.spooldir-source.interceptors = i1
Agent5.sources.spooldir-source.interceptors.i1.type = org.flumefiles.flume.HtmlInterceptor$Buider
```

I've placed my jar file both into `/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/` and `/usr/lib/flume-ng/lib/`. Also I've created plugins.d at `/usr/lib/flume-ng/plugins.d/` and placed jar there. But when running flume agent I've got an error:

```
15/02/18 06:10:46 ERROR channel.ChannelProcessor: Builder class not found. Exception follows.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.intropro.flume.HtmlInterceptor$Buider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

.....

Where should I place my jar file to make it find builder?

Answer (score 0):

Place it into FLUME_HOME/lib and then restart flume.

If that doesn't work, make sure your interceptor actually implements the Builder interface. That might be another reason.